# Living place in USA

Tags: usa, budget

If iam travelling to work in USA, alone without my family, and I dont want to rent an apartment or studio, is there is the option of renting only a room and how much does it cost?

Comment: Yes there’s that option. Many people rent a room in a house or apartment. The price varies

Comment: average  Price  ?

Comment: The average price depends on the region you are going to. In San Francisco, count 3000-4000 USD/month. In rural areas in the middle of nowhere, think of 300-500 USD/month. AirBNB has some long-term rentals available and you may want to have a look for options in the region you are going to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Housing cost in the US varies by location. The middle of a big city or developed area (like Silicon Valley) will be very expensive, while smaller cities and towns will be cheaper. [Craigslist.org](http://Craigslist.org) is a good resource for shared housing.

I just looked at CraigsList for San Francisco, California. The cost for renting a room in a shared house ranges from $800/mo to $3000/mo.